Window jiggles on JavaFX window when opening/closing dialog on Linux
This is weird. I have a JavaFX application when run on Linux the window jiggles whenever you open and close another dialog. I notice that the maximize button is removed from the window when the dialog is displayed then added back when it is closed. I haven’t found anyone else complaining about this. I’ve included a dead simple application to show that I’m not doing anything remotely unusual. This happens whenever displaying any type of Dialog. Any thoughts?

Sorry for the terrible image, but the built-in screen recorder didn't actually record the jiggle.
I’m running java 21.0.3+9, JavaFX 19.0.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.
    public class Test extends Application
    {
       @Override
       public void start( Stage stage )
      {
          Button button = new Button( "Test" );
          button.setOnAction( e -> {
             Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE, "Hello", ButtonType.CLOSE );
             alert.initOwner( stage.getScene().getWindow() );
             alert.showAndWait();
          } );
          VBox vbox = new VBox();
          vbox.getChildren().add( button );
          stage.setScene( new Scene( vbox, 600, 800 ) );
          stage.show();
       }
    }


This app runs fine on Windows (no jiggle), but not on Linux. Swing works fine on this machine and I’m not seeing this behavior anywhere else. Any JavaFX app I run does this. This is a stock install of Ubuntu. No customization of the OS and the apps I run on it were direct downloads (like IntelliJ Idea), meaning I haven't altered the OS via any package managers or command-line tools.

An accessibility feature of the OS might cause behavior like this.  For example this is a configuration of a visual flash on the focused windows for an alert sound.  Also, test with the latest releases for Java and JavaFX and see if the issue reoccurs.

If you don't init the owner, does the issue still occur?

Commenting out setting the owner still causes it. Visual alerts are not enabled.

Do you have an autohide  panel in your Linux distro ? Try to deactivate that feature

I'm not certain what you mean about autohide. I just searched and came across Auto Hide Top Bar, but everything I saw had to be installed. This is a stock installation of Ubuntu. I see Panel Mode for the Dock. Changing that had no effect. Looked through settings and didn't see any relevant auto-hide options.

Please try to remove alert.initOwner() and use alert.setModal() (or something like that) if needed.

There's no setModel or similar method. Not sure what you're suggesting. But as stated above, removing setOwner doesn't fix it.
